# Video Chat: Scalability Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, scalability, red5, rtmp, videochat

We use Red5 media server as a back-end for our Flash video chat application. Recently we had a significant increase in user traffic, which brought the video chat down. While it is fairly straightforward to manage HTTP traffic using EC2 load balancers, we are not sure what to do with RTMP traffic.

How can we scale our media servers and manage RTMP traffic (using AWS or any other service)?

Answer (score 0):

[CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront) (Amazon's CDN) supports RTMP.